# Problem with tutorials

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

In the "[Using the Statemachine Editor](http://wiki.ros.org/flexbe/Tutorials/Using%20the%20Statemachine%20Editor)" tutorial one is told to go to **configuration** tab and do some stuff in the **State Library window**. The problem is that I don't see any **State Libray window**.

Here are the complete directions:

> Start implementing the behavior by adding FlexBe built-in state library to your FlexBe App. This state library is included in flexbe_behavior_engine/flexbe_states/src/flexbe_states. Go to configuration tab, in State Library window click Add Folder and select your flexbe_states folder. This procedure is also performed to add another state library that other people made.

Is this something I can just ignore?

regards
Frimann

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329268/problem-with-tutorials/) by [Frimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/41102/frimann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2019-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-25**:
Can you please update your question with a link to the tutorial that you're referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for pointing this out! Apparently, I missed it when I updated the tutorial from its previous version.

You can indeed ignore this paragraph, manually adding state packages is not required anymore. I already updated the tutorial now.

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2019-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1